# Is there any new architecture to developing asp.net applicarion other then 3-tire Architecture?

Tags: c#

Normaly we use 3-Tire Architecture.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: There are none... this is the only way you can build software

Comment: It's also `tier`, not `tire` :) But this isn't really an SO question, you're better of looking this type of information up via the internet (Google).

Comment: we also able to use Repository pattern instaed of 3-tire. Is this right?

Comment: As a every developer known about 3-tire architecture. for developing project. Is any new way to achieve 3-tire architeture?

Comment: repository pattern is a design pattern, not an architecture

Comment: Or new way to get the data using data access layer. Using dictionaty like this.

Comment: L-three. Am using DAL like this                                public DataSet GetDetails(string ProcessCycleID)
       {
           DataSet DS = new DataSet();

           Intialize(StoredProcedureName.locationDetails);
           DBName.AddInParameter(DBComm, "@ProcessD", DbType.String, ProcessID);
           return DS = DBName.ExecuteDataSet(DBComm);

       }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use the [onion architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) in combination with CQS (practical example [here](http://ludwigstuyck.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/a-reference-architecture-part-1/)).

Comment: Is better than 3-tire architecture?

Comment: It's a personal taste probably, but to me it's a more flexible approach with clear dependencies. The links I showed explain this in more detail.

Comment: @l-tree Can you share link for Onion Architecture using asp.net MVC

Comment: What link do you mean?

Comment: @L-Tree,I need sample code  using onion architecture in mvc

Comment: The second link can help you started. The services exposed in the services layer are used by your controllers in the presentation layer (the C in MVC). In your case you might use them directly as a class library, or using WCF or WebAPi.

Comment: Onion architecture is closely related to repository pattern. Is this Correct.

Comment: Where do you get that? Repository pattern is just a design pattern that could be used, but doesn't have to be used. This has nothing to do with the principles of onion architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Below few architectures are practicing in the software developing :

1. Client–server model
2. Database-centric architecture
3. Front-end and back-end
4. Hierarchical internetworking model
5. Open Services Architecture
6. Rich Internet application
7. Service layer
8. Web application
9. Multilayered architecture

Comment: You can also just show the link from which this is copied: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture